# Is there a reason a dll from an installed program would only not work on one system?

Tags: excel, vba, dll

I've written a relatively simple VBA tool for Excel that interfaces with a third party program to send/receive data to my company's data system. The third party program is enterprise software that installs the API dll by default. The program is accessible (through this dll) on every machine in my office that has tried, except one. Every attempt with this machine yields run-time error 429.

I have tried:

1) Uninstall and reinstall software (both third part program and Excel) - no change

2) regsvr32 /u and /i to fix the dll reference - /i fails with the missing entry point message

3) Adding the explicit reference to the dll via the VBA editor (it is listed) and switching from late to early binding - same 429 error

4) Switching machines. Supposedly this user had changed computers several months ago and things worked for a bit but have since stopped again.

5) Copy working program files from one pc to the nonworking pc - same error

I have verified that the error occurs in the code only when I attempt to create the object, so the problem has to be with how the system is handling the dll in question.

Is there anything else that could be driving this issue? Can user permissions issues manifest in this way? I'm pretty much out of things to try.

Comment: Can you use createobject successfully in (eg) vbscript?  Does createobject work for other COM types besides this specific dll?  Is the user using a different version (or 64bit version) of Excel?  Checked the system error logs?

Comment: licensing?  429 means cannot create ActiveX component, this either means going through IClassFactory or IClassFactory2; if the latter then there will be licensing code.

Comment: You are going to have to familairise yourself with what goes on underneath the hood when you use `VBA.CreateObject` or `New`  Here is a nice diagram https://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2017/04/look-ma-no-registry-get-iclassfactory.html#aNiceDiagram

Comment: As Tim Williams says check the 32bit vs 64bit situation.  The "bitness" must match, you cannot load a 32-bit dll into a 64 bit Excel.exe and vice versa.  https://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/06/vba-python-python-com-class-has-own.html

Comment: I will need to check 32/64 bit when I'm back in the office. As an enterprise install, Excel shouldn't be different on this one PC. The dll installs to program files (x86) but runs perfectly on other x64 systems.

Comment: Looks like it was a bit issue. For some reason this one user has a 64 bit office install...Forcing it back to x32 should fix things.